# Can I add IF clause to TRY & EXCEPT clause

Tags: python, if-statement, try-except

*Please pardon me if I make any formatting issues here!*

I am creating 2 variables, namely the mean and variance. Still working on the "variance" variable so please ignore that part.

**Here's the background:**

The mean and variance are int inputs. The mean can be of any value, on the other hand, the variance will need to be of value greater than 1. And whenever, the input prompts, and the users hit enter straightaway (without any inputs), the mean and variance will be 0 and 1 respectively.

I have attempted the question and want to integrate both the TRY & EXCEPT clause with the IF clause because to check of ValueError and to automatically stop the program if the users hit enter without any values...

I am not sure if this is doable, can anyone advise, please... Many thanks!

**Here's my code:**

```
mean = 0
variance = 1

valid_input = False
while valid_input == False:
    try:
        mean = int(input("Please enter the mean value: "))
        if mean == "":
            valid_input = True
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a numeric value!")
    else:
        valid_input = True
print (mean, variance)
```

Comment: what is your question? is your code not working or are you trying to improve your code?

Comment: Hi, the code runs. But when I attempt to press enter without any inputs, it doesn't break..

Comment: you are taking input inside try-except so it will not break

Comment: Hmm... What can I do about this then?

I have attempted isnumeric() way to check for errors, but it wouldn't allow me to enter a negative value. So I doubt I should approach that method.

Comment: if you want to break the code for invalid input then don't use try-except or move the input conversion to `int` to after the `if` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mean = 0
variance = 1
mean = input("Please enter the mean value: ")
try:
    mean = int(mean)
    print (mean, variance)
except ValueError:
    print("Please enter a numeric value!")
```

This works. If the input is not an int, `Please enter a numeric value` is printed and the program exits.

Or you can use the following code to determine if the user input is an integer, and if it is, you can convert it to int. You won't need the try-except block now. [Ref](https://codippa.com/check-if-string-is-integer-in-python/)

```
import re
# read value from keyboard
value = input("Enter a string\n")
# match the entered value to be a number
result = re.match("[-+]?\d+$", value)
# check if there was a match
if result is not None:
    print("Entered string is an integer")
    print(int(value))
else:
    # entered value contains letters also
    print("Entered string is not an integer")
```

Comment: Hi HiEd, yes that works. But I need to consider another criteria for mean variable - which is, if the user inputs nothing, then the mean and variance will automatically be 0 and 1 respectively. So how do I add the criteria of that along with this following code?

Comment: Awesome! Its working for me now! Thanks for your help!!

Moving onto the second part which is the variance variable. I am trying to set a condition. If input variance is <= 0, an error message should prompt. However, it seems like relational operators are not supported between instances of re.match and int. Any suggestions pls?

Comment: [Update] Managed to complete it! By converting the str into int for the relational operators!

Comment: Great. Please accept the post as the answer then

Comment: Can you advice how I can accept this pot as the answer? Can't seem to flag it up as my reputation is below 15 haha